# Single website with multiple certs

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, ssl-certificate

I have a website with 2 domain names.
1. name.org
2. server.university.edu/name

I have a wildcard cert to cover server.university.edu/name. If I get one from say, letsencryp.org, I'm not sure how to use both for one website.

I'm using:
RHEL 8,
Apache2.4,
PHP 7.2

Do I need to create 2 vhosts and point the docroot to the same location or can I put mutilple certs into a single vhost? Or is there another better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use two vhosts and point them to the same document root or redirect one of them to the other url.

Letsencrypt allows you to have multiple domains in a single cert - if this is an option for you, you can use that with a single vhost.

But for flexibility I would prefer the first option...

Comment: Thank you for the information. I think I prefer the first option also.